React Native Ios Update (0.74.2) - App store connect/TestFlight - ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration in ios/pod/PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
After updating React Native to "react-native": "0.74.2", Added a file called PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy in ios/pod. However, the App Store app submission fails to approve builds with the following error:
Please correct the following issues and upload a new binary to App Store Connect.

ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
for the
“GoogleMaps.bundle/GMSCoreResources.bundle/GMSShaders.metallib” file
contains “C617.1” as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons
key instead of a valid reason code for using an API in the
NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults category. Values for
NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be
valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more
details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs
and approved reasons for usage, visit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
for the “Frameworks/libswift_Concurrency.dylib” file contains “C617.1”
as the value for a NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a
valid reason code for using an API in the
NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults category. Values for
NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy manifest must be
valid reason codes for the corresponding API category. For more
details about this policy, including a list of required reason APIs
and approved reasons for usage, visit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.
ITMS-91055: Invalid API reason declaration - The PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy
for the “AEO Middle East” file contains “C617.1” as the value for a
NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons key instead of a valid reason code for
using an API in the NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryUserDefaults category.
Values for NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons keys in any privacy
manifest must be valid reason codes for the corresponding API
category. For more details about this policy, including a list of
required reason APIs and approved reasons for usage, visit:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/privacy_manifest_files/describing_use_of_required_reason_api.


FIX 1 : Generic solution to fix PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy related issue.

Update your APIs based on the provided official URL:

Let's take an example of the API NSPrivacyAccessedAPICategoryActiveKeyboards in the file.

PrivacyInfo.xcprivacy

This API has only two valid NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons:

3EC4.1 and 54BD.1

We have to ensure we use only these under it. If we add any other NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons, it will cause an issue.
FIX 2 : Even if you have removed and corrected all NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons, In case you still face the same issues. This could be because, at the time of pod install, some dependencies add incorrect NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons. To fix this issue, add privacy_file_aggregation_enabled: false in your Podfile:
use_react_native!(
  # Disables the aggregation of privacy information from dependencies to prevent them from adding incorrect NSPrivacyAccessedAPITypeReasons
  privacy_file_aggregation_enabled: false,
  :path => config[:reactNativePath],

  # An absolute path to your application root.
  :app_path => "#{Pod::Config.instance.installation_root}/.."
)

